# How to pass Double quotes on java script through URL?

Tags: javascript

How to pass double quotes on **javascript** value in URL? 
eg:

```
onclick='window.location = "name.php?&fname=Ant"hony"babu &lastname=Stevens "boy
```

Comment: In this case (`onclick` that just sets `window.location`) you should probably just use a good old `<a href="...">` tag.

Comment: This is a bad practice. You should use a function for avoiding issues like what you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function for it:

```
onclick = function(){
    window.location.href += 'name.php?&fname=Ant"hony"babu &lastname=Stevens boy';
};
```

Comment: I assumed you needed to add that string to the whole url so thats why I added .href and +=.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **"** you can use **&quot;**:

```html
<button onclick="window.location='name.php?&fname=Ant&quot;hony&quot;babu &lastname=Stevens &quot;boy'">Click Me</button>
```